# calculate circle cardboard segments

Tags: geometry, circles

I want to make a cardboard lamp, but i want it to look like half a sphere.

Given a cardboard thickness of x, and a circle width of y, how many elements do I need and what radius do the elements need to be?  Anyone got a formula for that?

thanks alot!

[image: example of lamp and segments]

Comment: by half a circle, do you mean half a sphere? could you be more clear? my interpretation is that you want to stack up many cardboard circles to make a half of a sphere. Is this right?

Comment: so does my answer use the correct interpretation? It looks like it does from the image you have given - thanks for that, also.

Comment: yes, i meant half a sphere! (not native english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have interpreted your question as meaning that you want a stack of cardboard circles, making a half sphere when glued together.

If this is the case, then you will need $y\over2x$ individual cardboard rings.

Starting from the bottom, if you are on the $n^{th}$ ring up (the first ring at the bottom is $n=0$) then the formula for the ring's radius is $\sqrt{\left({y\over2}\right)^2-(nx)^2}$

Correct me if my interpretation is wrong.

Comment: thank you, this is wat I was looking for.

Comment: thank you, this is wat I was looking for.  I now know that I was looking for a circle's [chord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_%28geometry%29).  For the individual ring amount, is that correct?  Isn't it: ((y/2)/x) ?